# JavaScript in Java code throwing exception

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function from Java code. My code is as follows:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
                ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

                String script = baseUrl + "UIConfigurator/includes/js/DataCaptureFramework.js";                 

                  try {
                    LOGGER.info("evaluating engine");
                    LOGGER.info(script);
                    URL url1 = new URL(script);
                    LOGGER.info("url1 "+url1.getPath()+url1);

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url1.openStream()));
                    String inputLine = null;
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        buffer.append(inputLine);                   
                    LOGGER.info(buffer.toString());
                    engine.eval(buffer.toString());                     


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                    LOGGER.error("Throwing error in the catch part"); 
                }
                Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("invoking function");
                    inv.invokeFunction("displayDataCapturePopUp("+user.getOrgId()+","+user.getId()+","+session.getLoginType()+");");
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    LOGGER.error("throwing error in catch block of invoking engine and function");
                }
```

When I run this code it gives me the following error:

> 11:53:50,847 ERROR [Login] javax.script.ScriptException:
>   sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError:
>   "jQuery" is not defined. (#1) in  at
>   line number 1 11:53:50,847 ERROR [Login] Throwing error in the catch
>   part 11:53:50,848 INFO  [Login] invoking function 11:53:50,848 ERROR
>   [STDERR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method:
>   displayDataCapturePopUp(301,1373864,0);

I tried a lot of things but still cannot get rid of this. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to call the below function from JavaScript.

```
function displayDataCapturePopUp(orgId,userId,loginTypeId){ jQuery("              <link/>", {rel: "stylesheet",type: "text/css",href: 
"/UIConfigurator/includes/css/librarycss/jquery-ui.min.css"}).appendTo("head"); jQuery("<link/>", {rel: "stylesheet",type: "text/css",href: 
"/UIConfigurator/includes/css/DataCaptureFramework.css"}).appendTo("head"); jQuery("<link/>", {rel: "stylesheet",type: "text/css",href: 
"/UIConfigurator/includes/css/librarycss/tooltipster.css"}).appendTo("head");   jQuery("<link/>", {rel: "stylesheet",type: "text/css",href: 
"/UIConfigurator/includes/css/librarycss/jquery.alerts.css"}).appendTo("head"); 
jQuery.getScript('/UIConfigurator/includes/js/UiAjaxInteraction.js',function()  {       
jQuery.getScript('/iONjsLib/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js',function()      {           
jQuery.getScript('/iONjsLib/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js',function()            {               
jQuery.getScript('/UIConfigurator/includes/js/libraryjs/jquery.alerts.js',function()                {                   
jQuery.getScript('/iONjsLib/js/jquery.blockUI.js',function()                    {                       
getDataCapturePopUpDetails(orgId,userId,loginTypeId);                           }
                );              
                                                                                }
                );          
                                                                                }
                );      
                                                                        }
                );  
                                                                                }
                );
                                                        }
```

Comment: When asking for help, please format your code readably.

Comment: The JavaScript function you're trying to call depends on JQuery, and you haven't done anything to make JQuery available to it, so it fails.

Comment: It says "jQuery" is not available. You know that `jQuery` is not part of standard Javascript, don't you? Did you include its definition in the script?

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptEngine` runs JavaScript in an entirely separate environment, with no access to your browser. It looks like you're trying to use it to show some kind of popup in your browser; this will not work. If you need to control your browser remotely, you need to use a different API, not `ScriptEngine`.